# Where in a "block"

Tags: haskell

I am doing a program that have very similar code blocks, and I was trying to make a where in a "block". 
Just an example

```
function "sum" x = x + a
function "product" x = x * a
  where 
    a = 2
```

I want the 'a' to be replaced in both lines, but I didn't find out if this is possible using where

Thanks in advance

Comment: The syntax is wrong if this is indeed Haskell.

Should be `sum x = x + 2`

And you need a `where` block for each function declaration, they can't be 'shared'.

Comment: Actually I would call `function "sum" 2`, which would give me 4, for example. But thank you, it seems it's really not possible

Comment: ah I see what you're doing. typically you would use an algebraic datatype instead of strings to accomplish what you want. `data Operation = Sum | Product` and then do `function Sum x = x + 2`.

if you want to use the same `a` you should consider using a Reader monad

Comment: Yeah, I am using an algebraic datatype, but I prefer to use a "simpler" example just to ask about the where question

Comment: yup definitely take a look at the Reader monad. seems like you want an environment under which to evaluate the functions (where `a` is bound to 2 for instance)

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mtl/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-Monad-Reader.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need this, you need to merge the two function clauses. One way to do this:

```
func what x = case what of
        "add" -> x+a
        "mul" -> x*a
    where
       a = 2
```

Comment: Note that defining a function multiple times for different arguments, as shown in the question, is really just syntactic sugar for a `case` block like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can also introduce a second function:

```
function fName x = function' fName x
   where
      a = 2
      function' "sum"     x = x + a
      function' "product" x = x * a
```

Answer (score 0):

(Forgive me because I'm a newbie.)  I don't think this is possible.  The scope of the `where` "block" is the function it's defined in.  What you can do is this, though:

```
Prelude> let a = 2
Prelude> let sum x = x + a
Prelude> let product x = x * a
Prelude> sum 3
5
```

This is done in GHCi.  You may be concerned that *everyone* can see `a`, but if this were in a .hs file, you could make it a module and just not export `a`, and then only these functions could see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can define a new function geta

```
geta=2
```

And then you can use the geta function in any other functions.

I don't think mix every functions is a good way, 
maybe you will have 20 functions need the same value